# My Windows 8 computer is booting up with USB disabled, so I can't log in

Tags: windows-8, boot, usb, keyboard, mouse

My Windows 8 computer has today started booting up (or possibly restarting) with the USB ports disabled, which means that my USB keybaord and mouse are not working, and I can't log in. I can press the power  button, and the PC seems to power down (or go into sleep or hibernate - I can't tell). I can press the power button again, and it seems to power up again (or resume from sleep/hibernate). But the mouse and keyboard are dead, so I can't do anything else. I can get into BIOS by repeatedly pressing function keys during boot-up, and then the mouse power light comes on, and the keyboard works, so I *know* this is not a hardware problem.

What is Windows likely to have done that has disabled the USB ports? Given that I can't get into Windows, how do I correct this?

Thanks - Rowan

Comment: If you cannot solve it trying the answers here, boot the PC from a linux live   cd or usb, then while in linux delete the hiberfil.sys file on the root of C:. Exit linux and try booting again.

Answer (score 1):

When you are at your login screen, try switching your USB devices to different ports. If your devices were disabled in Windows somehow, swapping them to a new port should cause them to be re-enabled. Windows generally disables USB devices based off what the device is, and what port it is plugged into. Plugging into a new port should allow you to regain use and diagnose why they are not working in that particular port.

The other option is that your USB controller itself is disabled in Windows. If that is the case, try moving your devices to other ports on your PC. Hopefully, you have a second set of ports running off a different controller (i.e. USB 3.0 ports) that will still be working.